# change the variable JSF from SelectOneMenu

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jstl

I have setted a JSF Varidable Like this:

```
<c:set var="selectedech" value="#{ManagedBean.selectedtypeFacturation}" scope="request"/>
```

After that i putted it on a SelectOneMenu:

```
 <p:selectOneMenu  panelStyle="width: 120px" effect="fade" id="typeFacture"  value="#{selectedech}" >
        <f:selectItem itemValue="Echeancier" itemLabel="Echeancier"/>
        <f:selectItem itemValue="Mensuel" itemLabel="Mensuel"/>
        <p:ajax event="change"  update="@this"/>
 </p:selectOneMenu>
```

I would like to change the value of JSF variable "selectedech" each time i change the selection.

Any idea in order to get it work well

Thx

Comment: Why exactly did you add `scope="request"`? This is the cause of your problem.

Comment: No, even without the scope, i couldn't change the value of "selectedech" when i select another item from SelectOneMenu